# How can I add a value to an array's key from another array with the same key in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following 2 arrays:

```
$a = [ 'post_type' => 'ese' ];
$b = [ 'demo_handle' => 'demo-3', 'post_type' => [ 'aaa', 'bbb' ], 'id' => 3'];
```

I would like for `$b` to "adopt" `$a`'s values, but not the other way around. My final array would look like:

```
$c = [ ..., 'post_type' => [ 'aaa, 'bbb', 'ese'], ...];
```

How can I achieve this? I've tried multiple methods but none seem to `array_merge` correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use looping with `isset()` function. More details in code comments below:

```
// Loop over the $b array
foreach ($b as $key => $value) {

    // Check if this key exists in $a array also
    if (isset($a[$key])) {

        // if exists, we can merge them 
        // We need to typecast value in $a to array 
        // since, array_merge requires array arguments
        $b[$key] = array_merge((array)$value, 
                               (array)$a[$key]);
    }
}
```

### [Rextester DEMO](https://rextester.com/VJHN80319)

Comment: Oh yea, that's how I did it but isn't there an inbuilt array method to deal with this?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya This works and differently to `array_merge_recursive`, it doesn't give me duplicates.

Comment: @coolpasta at the end of the day, any built-in PHP function will also be doing looping and same conditional checks etc. Sometimes to avoid inadvertent behaviour, it is better to write a small loop code by ourselves. This ensures that our specific requirements are met completely.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a function called [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php):

```
$c = array_merge_recursive($a, $b);
```

Comment: I promise I always do due dilligence before even THINKING about asking on SO, but this doesn't work :/

Comment: @coolpasta Hmm, it should work. The documentation's example is almost identical to yours.

Comment: Works as described: https://3v4l.org/SmBpf Maybe be more descriptive about why it doesn't do what you want.